# Catching shp2psql errors from python's subprocess module

Tags: python, postgresql, shp2pgsql, subprocess

I'm importing data into postgresql with shp2psql and pyhton's subprocess module.

```
command = 'shp2pgsql -s {SRID} -a -g geom -W "UTF-8" {SHP_path} {table_name} -I | ' \
          'psql -h {hostname} -p {port} -d {db_name} -U {username}'\
    .format(SRID=4326, SHP_path=shp_file, table_name=table_name, 
            hostname=hostname, port=port, db_name=db_name, username=username)

subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

The problem is that I cannot intercept import errors like

```
ERROR: 
current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

They are happening internally and don't stop the subprocess from execution so I have no means to control the result of execution. Is there any way to raise such errors in the main code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you use Python 2.7. 
You can change to *check_call* method of subprocess and you can redirect stdin, stdout and stderr, see: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html
Using Python 3.5+ you have more control.

Comment: My Pyhton version is 3.4.2